# Defineing dot function on a String to call several function

Tags: javascript

I wonder how I can define some dot function in js like `.toupperCase` that can call on a string or object without getting any  parameters. For example I want to define a function on a string that calls a several function itself like

```js
let ex = "hi .this is  &$234234 a test @#";
let tmp = ex.textformating();

String.prototype.textformating = function (){
    return this.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]/gi, '  ').trim();
}
```

Comment: Just like that! Except you need to define it *before* you call it.

Comment: Note that expanding standard objects like so is not recommended. (1) It creates confusion between built-in methods and your own code. (2) It might not work on all browsers. (3) It might break if a browser eventually adds a method with the same name. Just create a function that takes the string as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. You just have to define the function **before** you call it.

```js
String.prototype.textformating = function (){
    return this.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]/gi, '  ').trim();
}

let ex = "hi .this is  &$234234 a test @#";
let tmp = ex.textformating();

console.log('original:', ex)
console.log('formatted:', tmp)
```